# Font Size Disabling - Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How could the font size be disabled is a Xamarin.iOS app/code?  I had done this in Xamarin.Android app using the following code:

```cs
private void initFontScale()
{
    Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
    configuration.FontScale = (float)1.45;
    //0.85 small, 1 standard, 1.15 big，1.3 more bigger ，1.45 supper big 
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;
    BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
}
```

What would be the equivalent of doing this in an iOS Xamarin app?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is Font Size Disabling in Xamarin iOS? What you want to achieve? Setting the different font size with different screenSize in iOS app?

Comment: I'm trying to keep the font at a particular size in the app regardless of what people have set the font size in the iPhone/iPad settings.  So I'm trying to either figure out a way to disable the font settings or reset/rescale the font size(like I had done above in the android code).

Comment: In my knowledge, I don't think the system font settting will affect your app's font szie only if you listen to the [uicontentsizecategorydidchangenotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategorydidchangenotification?language=objc).

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your App code behind before you initialise your pages:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<iOS>().SetEnableAccessibilityScalingForNamedFontSizes(false);
```

You'll need to include these:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
```